# react router v4 exact prop trigger 2 component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

`<Route exact path='/admin/task/create' component={ComponentA} />
<Route exact path='/admin/task/:id' component={ComponentB} />`

I visit `http://localhost:3000/task/123` it will trigger ComponentB, but when I hit `http://localhost:3000/task/create` it will hit ComponentB and ComponentA, why is it so? I thought exact prop alrdy solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your routers independent of each other, so the second router receives "create" as :id.

You have to wrap your routers with the `Switch`

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/admin/task/create' component={ComponentA} />
    <Route exact path='/admin/task/:id' component={ComponentB} />
</Switch>
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md